# how to check in only set of files changed into subversion

Tags: svn

How to check in only selected files changed in to the repository?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just give the file names to the commit command:

```
svn commit -m "Fixed a bad bug" file1 file2
```

If you are using subversion 1.5 or newer, you could instead create a [changelist](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.changelists.html).

```
svn changelist mychanges file1 file2
```

will create a changelist called `mychanges` and assign the files `file1` and `file2` to it.

Then you can commit the changelist, or use the changelist on many other commands as well:

```
svn commit -m "Fixed a bad bug" --changelist mychanges
```

Answer (score 7):

Just tell Subversion which files you want to check in.

```
svn commit FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 ...
```

You may also find the [changelist](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html#changelists) feature, introduced with 1.5 useful. See [this section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.changelists.html) of the [book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using TortoiseSVN, a dialog box appears when you do a commit that allows you to deselect any files you don't want to commit.

If you are using a command-line tool, check the documentation for the commit function of that tool, it should allow you to specify which files to include.